# How to hide many lines in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering how to do this manually. I don't like folding because it still shows the method declaration line. But I have noticed that after leaving a method folded for a while eventually those line numbers are hidden completely. I was wondering if there was a way I could do this manually and hide an entire chunk of lines. Here is an  of what I am talking about.

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw6Ta.png)

Comment: If your class is that big that you prefer to hide some code, then you probably should think about refactoring that class and reducing its size.

Comment: Then extract that stuff into a library.